# Remove word from string in python (not just letters which matches)

Tags: python, string

Say I have a string `hi the Eifeltower is way to high for me to climb` and I want to remove `hi`.
Doing `x.replace("hi","")` wont work since it also removes the `hi` in `high`.

Isnt there a function in python that removes words, and not collections of characters? w/o having to write some regex?

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to use regex:

```
x = "your string"
forbidden= ["your", "list", "of", "forbidden", "words"]
" ".join([word for word in x.split() if not word in forbidden])
```

Comment: Yeah, thats the approach I came up with aswell. Just weird ther isnt a a build in for that

Comment: @CutePoison if you did came up with that before I post an answer, you should mention it in your question and save me the effort.

Comment: Sorry, I came up with it while waiting for a reply :)

Comment: @CutePoison np :)